# POST request parameter value's encoding

Tags: c#, post, encoding, httpclient

I'm trying to do POST requests (searching something on the somethis url) to a specific URL, in c# with HttpClient, and there is problem with encoding: with "test" (below code) value works fine, it gives me search result, and with words in another alphabet ("тест") it doesn't give me result.

By the way on the site searching works fine with all words. In the first case Firefox (Inspect Element -> Network -> POST request -> Parameters) shows parameter like that: search:test, and in the second case shows: search:òåñò . I've tried to send "òåñò" instead of "тест" with no success. What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

```
try
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        KeyValuePair<string, string> param = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("search", "test");

        parameters.Add(param);

        HttpContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        httpRequestMessage.Content = httpContent;

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        string respBodyEncoded = encoding.GetString(responseBody);

    }
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're not URL encoding the other language. For simple US-ASCII characters such as 'test' URL encoding is not necessary, but "тест" isn't within US-ASCII range therefore should be URL encoded.

So in your case, the "тест" parameter should be `%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82`

Here's the relvant RFC for URLs:
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

> Octets must be encoded if they have no corresponding graphic
>      character within the US-ASCII coded character set, if the use of the
>      corresponding character is unsafe, or if the corresponding character
>      is reserved for some other interpretation within the particular URL
>      scheme.